# How can import one contract functions in solidity

Tags: contract-development, import

Looking at the solidity documentation i don´t find a date type. Searching in the web I find a GitHub repo that appear one contract that give the posibility to work with date.

https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime/blob/master/contracts/DateTime.sol

My problem is that I don´t know how can import one contract inside other contract. Any help??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by putting this contract in your directory and importing it in your main contract and inherit it. You can import any file by using this syntax on the top of your file:
`import <filename>;`

You can check various ways to `import` here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=import#import

To understand inheritance in solidity, this can be helpful : https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/contracts.html#inheritance

To avoid `import`, you can directly copy the contract in the same file of your contract.

Answer (score 3):

In solidity we can import a contract in different ways.

Simple way of importing contract:

`import "<filename>";`

Using a global symbol whose members are all the global symbols from contract file :

`import * as globalSymbolName from "<filename>";`

For avoiding name collision in contracts we can use alias :

`import {symbol1 as alias, symbol2} from "filename";`

By specifying path :

`import "./filename" as filename;`

`import "<contract url>" as mapping_name;`

Answer (score 1):

You can import directly like:
[image]

but there is some error in import link:**https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime/blob/master/contracts/DateTime.sol**

So, You can import it in another way like go to this Github link and copy all content of DateTime.sol file and create the same name of a file in your remix IDE and import it.